# Why obj[-0] not equal to obj['-0'] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript

```
var obj = {
  '34': 'I am 34',
  '-777': 'I am -777',
  '0': 'I am 0'
}
obj[34]   // 'I am 34'
obj[-777] // 'I am -777'
obj[0]    // 'I am 0'
```

It seems that `obj[number]` equal `obj[number.toString()]`. But it comes different with `-0` and `+0`:

```
var obj = {
  '-0': '-0 here',
  '+0': '+0 here'
}
obj[+0]; // undefined
obj['+0']; // '-0 here'

obj['0'] = 'just 0';
obj[+0]; // 'just 0'
obj[-0]; // 'just 0'
```

Why?

Comment: I would assume it is because `-0` and `+0` get compiled first and so what is actually being passed is the result of `-1*0` (which is 0) and `+1*0` (again,0).

Comment: Have you tried `(-0).toString()` and `(+0).toString()`?

Comment: @Bergi Oh thank you I haven't notice this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that `obj[number]` equal `obj[number.toString()]`.

Yes. In ECMAScript 5, all properties have property names that are strings - and whatever you pass into the property access operator (bracket notation) is implicitly cast to a string.

> But it comes different with `-0` and `+0`

No, it's the same for those. You seem to be confused by the fact that both `String(-0)` and `String(+0)` yield `"0"`, but that's just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

`+0` is an integer. Of course, +0=0. We're talking about the index `0` of an array (which `obj` is not).

`'+0'` is a string and it's not the same thing. It's the property `'+0'` of the object, exactly the same as if it was 'asd'.

Note that, in JS, `[ ]` work for both arrays and objects. `obj['asd']` represents `obj.asd` (but you cannot write `obj.+0` because it's not a valid property name).

Comment: There is not much of a difference between arrays and objects in JS. `…[…]` works *exactly the same* on them. And yes, every Array is an object.

Comment: You can't use `obj.+0` because `+0` is not an IdentifierName.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know is that Javascript handles objects and arrays very similarly. If you were to initialize an array `x = [1,2,3]` you could treat it very similarly to the object `x = {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3}`, and therefore you can index them as such. `x[0] === x['0']`.

So when you do `x[0]` you can think of the key as being converted to a string first. You can try these in the console

```
(-0).toString()  // == "0"
(0).toString()   // == "0"
(+0).toString()  // == "0"
```

The parentheses here are important because order of operations matter. The stuff in the parentheses gets evaluated first and then used as a key. Thats why you can do a mathematical operation inside of an index like `x[1+1] === x[2]`. So therefore `x[+0]` can be thought of as `x[(+0).toString()] -> x[(0).toString()] -> x['0']`.

So finally, its easy to see why numerical values `0 === +0 === -0` but string values `'0' != '+0' != '-0'`, and therefore the keys are different, and hence `x[0] === x[+0]` but `x[+0] != x['+0']` because `x['0'] != x['+0']`

Comment: hum, `x = {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3}` won't inherit the Array's prototype methods (`x.sort` => `undefined`) it's more that indexes of Arrays are just Object keys.